# How to return count in Rest API

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I'd like to return a count of some articles, how should the URL looks like? Does it make sense to be `/api/articles/count`? I do not have a resource to return articles and do not need to do that, I am interested only in the count.

Comment: I would probably name that object differently. E.g /api/articles/info or /api/articles/metadata if you would want to extend it with more metadata in the future. Anyways, the structure of the url makes sense but think of what that object should represent.

Comment: The resource identifier can be anything you want.  `/api/articles/count` is fine

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to be /api/articles/count?

Sure it makes sense.

Just to mention the URI structure does not matter that much if your api meets the HATEOAS constraint of REST.